# Sync local web server with remote web server

Tags: software-recommendation, webserver, sync

Hi I'm looking for a tool to synchronize files from my local web server to remote web server. I've been using since a few of years the  ([Site Publisher](http://www.sitepublisher.net/overview.html)) with wine, but I'm looking for a free alternative that integrates naturally with Ubuntu (a linux aplication).

I would like the tool had GUI like Meld, which could have a list of files / directories to ignore, that I can choose which files or directories you want to replace at the time of synchronization, in few words something like the Site Publisher mention that before.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest rsync, if you want a graphical interface grsync

I would advise using rsync/grsync over ssh

See:

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grsync.html

http://ayozone.org/2009/12/21/how-to-use-grsync-with-ssh/

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I already knew the rsync but does not offer me what I want, I can not manually select different files and decide what to do with them, the closest thing to what I need is the directory comparison option of Filezilla  but the work is manual and is a bit cumbersome.